# get monthly record of employees in one query using mysql

Tags: php, sql

I am using this query for getting monthly record of employees those are present and absent.
However i am getting the result for one employee by using this query but for all employees it doesn't seems to work.

```
SELECT 
    m.emp_id AS `Empid`,
    d.dt AS `AbsentDate`,
    (CASE
        WHEN p.punch_status IS NULL THEN 'A'
        ELSE p.punch_status
    END) s
FROM
    (SELECT 
        DATE(t.added_date) AS dt
    FROM
        pmc_attendance t
    WHERE
        DATE(t.added_date) >= '2018-08-01'
            AND DATE(t.added_date) < DATE_ADD('2018-08-31', INTERVAL 1 DAY)
    GROUP BY DATE(t.added_date)
    ORDER BY DATE(t.added_date)) d
        CROSS JOIN
    tbl_admin_users m
        LEFT JOIN
    pmc_attendance p ON DATE(p.added_date) >= d.dt
        AND DATE(p.added_date) < d.dt + INTERVAL 1 DAY
        AND p.emp_id = m.emp_id
WHERE
    p.emp_id IS NULL AND m.emp_id = '000838'
GROUP BY d.dt
ORDER BY m.emp_id , d.dt
```

I am using two tables 1. tbl_admin_users- employee data stored 2. pmc_attendance- present records of employees.
in query if i have passed the **and m.emp_id='000838'** it works fines but i want to show all records for all employees. any suggestions how i can optimize this query.

Comment: In order to help, please add some http://sqlfiddle.com/, and share some given data and the expected result

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to structure this query. I can see what yuo are doing, and I think the only issue is with your group by clauses. You dont need them as everything should be distinct. Your status will always be 'A' as you are only getting rows where there is no punch for the employee for the day, so you can also take out the case statement.

```
SELECT 
    m.emp_id AS Empid,
    d.dt AS AbsentDate,
    'A' s
FROM 
    (
    SELECT distinct DATE(t.added_date) AS dt 
    FROM pmc_attendance t 
    WHERE t.added_date >= '2018-08-01'  AND DATE(t.added_date) < DATE_ADD('2018-08-31', INTERVAL 1 DAY)
    ) d
CROSS JOIN tbl_admin_users m
LEFT JOIN pmc_attendance p ON p.emp_id = m.emp_id and DATE(p.added_date) >= d.dt AND DATE(p.added_date) < d.dt + INTERVAL 1 DAY
WHERE p.emp_id IS NULL 
ORDER BY m.emp_id , d.dt
```

If you want to include both present and absent, you would need to put your case statement back in, and remove your check `WHERE p.emp_id IS NULL`

If you have multiple punchs for the day, then you need to resolve it down to a single entry with a MIN/MAX so you only get one row per person per day, and add back in your `group by Emp_ID, d.dt`